# How to compare two Kappa values based on the same sample but different methods (two new methods A and B, and a gold standard method C)

Tags: cohens-kappa

Now, I have two assessment methods A and B (both of them are new methods) for assessing diabetes. Moreover, the method C is the gold standard.
Firstly, I ask a rater (Raters X) to use Method A and C (gold standard) to assess 50 individuals, respectively. I compute Cohen's Kappa based on the ratings (assuming the ratings are ordinal).
Secondly, I ask the same rater (Raters X) to use Method B to assess the same 50 patients (again, let's assume the ratings are ordinal). I compute Cohen's Kappa based on the Method B and Method C (which the results have been reported).

I wonder if there is a way to compare these two kappa statistics -- that is, whether they are statistically different.